# URLs break when a html page is ending with a slash

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a website say `www.domain.com`

It has a html page say at `www.domain.com/page.html`

It does not load when I add a / at the end as in

```
www.domain.com/page.html/
```

I think its because its trying to assume / as a folder and tries to see if there is anything inside the page.html folder.

So, how do I fix this? What needs to done to make all my .html files work fine even if:

1. I add a / at the end of them
2. I make it as just htm instead of html
3. I make it as all upper or mixed case as in .HTML or .hTML etc

Any solution with best practices please?

The reason is to direct all the traffic to the correct relevant pages of my site.

Comment: Can we see your `.htaccess` file? Is it throwing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?/?$ /$1.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this with localhost and you're not able to see localhost/domainexample/page.html/ because of trailing slash? if yes then you better look for virtual host so your domain will look like live domain